# How can I view locations of layers in PSD files without photoshop on osx?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, adobe-photoshop

I have some PSD files I had produced, but I don't have the positions of the layers aka images that were produced aka buttons etc.

I don't have photoshop.

I have tried gimp and pixelmator, but they don't show the coordinates of layers.

I have google how to do this for both of these packages, I can find the cursor position if I hover over the layers, but this isn't exact.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that there is a solution to this that is simpler than handing it off to someone who **does** have photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with this, but I found a [script that may help you](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=2268).

Comment: Doesn't that script require Photoshop?  Jules is looking for a solution that does not require photoshop.